# Array position using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, talend

How do you get the position of element using xpath . Example . I have an xml as below.

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
        <ID>12324234</ID>
        <FirstName>Something</FirstName>
        <LastName>Somethingelse</LastName>
    </c>
    <c>
        <ID>12324235</ID>
        <FirstName>Something</FirstName>
        <LastName>Somethingelse</LastName>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I am trying to extract the elements `id` using the xpath expression `/a/b/c/ID/text()` . What i am stuck up with is that, I want to extract the position as well.

Example

```
12324234 , 1
12324235 , 2
```

The comma is just for the understanding. I can use the xpath mentioned above to extract the data as step one and then use the xpath for position. Please note the array can have n values and not limited to 2.

I tried count , position etc but have no luck. Can anyone suggest me some options

Comment: So you want to create the `array` or use 1 `xPath` to get both your values?

Comment: @hiren :What i want is one column with position starting from 1 ---> N . where N is last position .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below XPath to get required output:

```
/a/b/c/concat(./ID/text(), ", ", (count(./preceding-sibling::c/ID) + 1))
```

*Output:*

```
12324234, 1
12324235, 2
```

Comment: Thanks  !! , Really appreciate your support. I tried the xpath in one of the online xpath testers and it says it cannot understand the expression: http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-xpath-tester.html . If you can have a look that would be great ,mean time let me try fixing it

Comment: Hmm... I tried in [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) and [this](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) and it works fine. What about the tool you use?

Comment: Strange  !! . it works in the link that you provided. Not sure but i guess it is more in the xpath 1.0 or 2.0 version thing , i am pretty new to xpath. I will be plugging this xpath in to a java function .